# Two equations related to a sport

Tags: sports, flags

How are these two equations related to a sport?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's related to

> Bowling

Because

> A 'strike' is marked with 'X' in Bowling and a 'spare' with '/', so
>  `Man x Nut` = Turkmenistan
>  `Jut / One` = [Esperantujo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantujo)
>  `Man Strike Nut` = Turkmenistan
>  `Jut Spare One` = Esperantujo
>  `Anagram of 'MANSTRIKENUT'` = Turkmenistan
>  `Anagram of 'JUTSPAREONE'` = Esperantujo